# Better Way to return multiple SQL Queries in one PHP page

Tags: php, sql

I am writing a website to compare cars to learn and understand PHP.  I have a sql table of cars - one are of say ford - which as a company id of 1 in my another table.  There is also a ModelLinkNo column in the table to link say saloon cars from Ford to saloon cars from BMW (which has a companyId of 2).

I want to display first a list of all ford company cars so my query is like below:

```
$getFordCars = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE CompanyId = '1'");
```

I then have multiple other querys below to bring back other cars which are off the same model - so like below:

```
$getSaloonCars = sprintf("SELECT * FROM CarsWHERE (CompanyId != '1' AND ModelLinkNo = '1')");
```

There are then other querys for get 4*4s get Hatchback, convertible, etc.

The data comes back from DB fine and I am wrting it to array as below:

```
<?php
    $fordCars = array();
    $otherSaloonCars = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fordCarsResult))
    {
        $fordCars [$i]= $row['ModelName'];
        $i++;
    }
    $j = 0;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($otherSaloonCarsResult))
    {
        $otherSaloonCars [$j]= $row2['ModelName'];
        $j++;
    }
?>
```

The above works and then I can retrieve the data for displaying further in my page - however is there a better way of doing this rather than having multiple while loops - as when I return all convertible models that would be another query and return 4*4's that will be another query and using the pattern I am using now that would result in writing a while loop for each query to write the results into an array

Comment: Start using PDO or MySQLi. `mysql_*` is deprecated. Also, learn prepared statements.

Comment: Hi Thanks @BartFriederichs - I will update to use MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about just downloading every ford car, and check on your backend site, if CompanyId is 1, or not, and pushing the data to the given array?

Also consider looking up for JOIN-ing your Cars table to itself, if needed.